# Connecting QAxObject event with a parameter of type IDispatch*

Tags: c++, qt, com, activeqt

I am trying to use ActiveQt library to handle an ActiveX event which has a parameter of type IDispatch*, such as following in an idl file.

```
// ...
library RecognitionClientLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX),
        helpstring("_IIFactoryEvents Interface")
    ]
    dispinterface _IIRecognizerFactoryEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(1), helpstring("method OnError")] void OnError(
                [in] LONG ilOperationCode,
                [in] BSTR iszDescription
                );
            [id(2), helpstring("method OnResult")] void OnResult(
                [in] IDispatch* ilpSource,
                [in] LONG ilOperationCode
                );
    };
    [
        uuid(XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX),
        control,
        helpstring("IFactory Class")
    ]
// ...
```

I used dumpcpp.exe and generated a header file and a cpp file for the object.
The generated file skipped the event generation as shown in the header file:

```
// skipping event interface _IIFactoryEvents
```

According to the document, IDispatch* argument should be converted to "QAxBase::asVariant()". Hence I tried to connect the events as following:

```
ClientLib::IFactory* lpFactory(new ClientLib::IFactory());
bool lbOk(connect(
    lpFactory,
    SIGNAL(OnError(
        int,
        const QString&
        )),
    SLOT(onError(
            int,
            const QString&
        ))
    ));
assert(lbOk);
lbOk = connect(
    lpFactory,
    SIGNAL(OnResult(
        QVariant,
        int
        )),
    SLOT(onResult(
        QVariant,
        int
        ))
    );
assert(lbOk);
```

which I have no problem connecting the signal of OnError but the connection of OnResult failed with

> Object::connect: No such signal
>   ClientLib::IFactory::OnResult(QAxObject*,int)

Please help me out on what parameter type should I use for an argument of IDispatch* type?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Nitpick: const references should be removed from signal/slot signatures you pass to connect, as well as whitespace - this saves a bit of runtime since Qt doesn't have to normalize the signatures. Thus `bool lbOk = connect(lpFactory, SIGNAL(OnError(int,QString)), SLOT(onError(int,QString)));`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will change them. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please help me out on what parameter type should I use for an argument
>   of IDispatch* type?

`IDispatch*` maps to `QAxObject*`: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qaxbase.html

Comment: Thanks for your elaborated answer. However my question was what the signature of the signal should I use. I cannot figure out the answer from the above reply though. :(

I have dug around and figured out that the argument should be the type of "IDispatch*". The assert passed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have found out the parameter type should be **IDispatch*** without modification despite the document said it was **QAxBase::asVariant()** for in parameter of type **IDispatch***.

Comment: Well done. It'd be great if you could submit that as a documentation bug to Qt bugtracker.